# What is wrong with my PHP on my apache2 web server (OS X 10.6)

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, apache, php

I have a web server on my mac mini that runs the default (installed with snow leopard) apache2 web server.  It works fine for any programming language that outputs stdout for cgi scripts, but every attempt I have made to enable PHP has failed.  Please help! I can upload any files that you need to see like php.ini or httpd.conf

I have tried scanning through the [php.ini](http://zachgottesman.com/php.ini) file values, php5 module load **is** uncommented in the [httpd.conf](http://zachgottesman.com/httpd.conf).
These are the only steps that I have seen to enable php on a mac.

php5, from what I hear, is installed by default on Mac OS X snow leopard.

Comment: Did you access your php files through http://localhost/~username or through file:///Users/username/Sites/ ?

Comment: @Matthieu Riegler try this link: zachgottesman.com/t.html that shows what is happening with php (view source of page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the following directive in your httpd.conf file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

**Edit**

To make this answer more useful for others, the full configuration for php on apache2 is:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Or whatever your path is your php module. This is the default path which come with Mountain Lion. Al I had to do was uncomment it. This is followed in the apache2.conf file with:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much.  And this is why I love stackexchange sites:  A problem I have had for years, is solved in a few days!